# Throwing an error stating variable doesn't exist

Tags: apex, error

Purpose/Overview : To update Region field when Country value is updated/Inserted

Public static void GE_PW_RegionUpdate(GE_PW_TriggerContextVariables tcv)

```
{ 
List<Opportunity> listreg = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity opp :(List<Opportunity >)tcv.newlist)
        {
          //  List<Tier3_Region__c> trObj = Tier3_Region__c.getInstance()
            List<Tier3_Region__c> trObj = Tier3_Region__c.getall().values();  
            for(Tier3_Region__c TR: trObj){
                if(TR.Country__c == Opp.GE_OG_Install_Country__c )              
                {
                    Opp.Tier_3_Install_Region__c    =   TR.Region__c;
                }
            }
            listreg.add(opp);
        }  
         insert listreg;
```

And the error message:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Tier3_Region__c at line

Comment: Please include the error message here verbatim so it's not just a guessing game.

Answer (score 8):

There are two errors on your code. First, the `getValues()` method for list custom settings, must receive a parameter that is the name of a custom setting 'record'. And it doesn't return a list.

The other error is that you are referencing a field from a list variable (wich doesn't exist), you need to reference the field from the sObject variable.

So instead of

```
trObj = Tier3_Region__c.getValues();  
for(Tier3_Region__c TR: trObj){
    if(TR.Country__c == Opp.GE_OG_Install_Country__c ){
        Opp.Tier_3_Install_Region__c    =   trObj.Region__c;
    }
}
```

You want

```
trObj = Tier3_Region__c.getAll().values(); //getAll() returns a Map, and values() gets a list of all the values on the map  
for(Tier3_Region__c TR: trObj){
    if(TR.Country__c == Opp.GE_OG_Install_Country__c ){
        Opp.Tier_3_Install_Region__c    =   TR.Region__c;
    }
}
```